# How do you get directory listing sorted by date in Elixir?

Tags: date, elixir, file-listing

How do you get directory listing sorted by date in Elixir?

`File.ls/1` gives list sorted by filename only.

No other functions in `File` module seem relevant for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe there's a built-in function I don't know about, but you can make your own by using [`File.stat!/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/File.html#stat!/2):

```elixir
File.ls!("path/to/dir")
|> Enum.map(&{&1, File.stat!(Path.join("path/to/dir", &1)).ctime})
|> Enum.sort(fn {_, time1}, {_, time2} -> time1 <= time2 end)
```

Example output:

```elixir
[
  {"test", {{2019, 3, 9}, {23, 55, 48}}},
  {"config", {{2019, 3, 9}, {23, 55, 48}}},
  {"README.md", {{2019, 3, 9}, {23, 55, 48}}},
  {"_build", {{2019, 3, 9}, {23, 59, 48}}},
  {"test.xml", {{2019, 3, 23}, {22, 1, 28}}},
  {"foo.ex", {{2019, 4, 20}, {4, 26, 5}}},
  {"foo", {{2019, 4, 21}, {3, 59, 29}}},
  {"mix.exs", {{2019, 7, 27}, {8, 45, 0}}},
  {"mix.lock", {{2019, 7, 27}, {8, 45, 7}}},
  {"deps", {{2019, 7, 27}, {8, 45, 7}}},
  {"lib", {{2019, 7, 27}, {9, 5, 36}}}
]
```

Comment: `... |> Enum.sort_by(&elem(&1, 1))`

Answer (score 2):

> **Edit**:
>   As pointed out in a comment, this assumes you're in the directory you want to see the output for. If this is not the case, you can specify it by adding the `:cd` option, like so:
>
> ```
> System.cmd("ls", ["-lt"], cd: "path/to/dir")
> ```

You can also make use of `System.cmd/3` to achieve this.

Particularly you want to use the `"ls"` command with the flag `"-t"` which will sort by modification date and maybe `"-l"` which will provide extra information.

Therefore you can use it like this:

```
# To simply get the filenames sorted by modification date

System.cmd("ls", ["-t"])

# Or with extra info

System.cmd("ls", ["-lt"])
```

This will return a tuple containing a String with the results and a number with the exit status.

So, if you just call it like that, it will produce something like:

```
iex> System.cmd("ls", ["-t"])
{"test_file2.txt\ntest_file1.txt\n", 0}
```

Having this, you can do lots of things, even pattern match over the exit code to process the output accordingly:

```
case System.cmd("ls", ["-t"]) do
  {contents, 0} ->
    # You can for instance retrieve a list with the filenames
    String.split(contents, "\n")
  {_contents, exit_code} ->
    # Or provide an error message
    {:error, "Directory contents could not be read. Exit code: #{exit_code}"
end
```

If you don't want to handle the exit code and just care about the contents you can simply run:

`System.cmd("ls", ["-t"]) |> elem(0) |> String.split("\n")`

> Notice that this will however include an empty string at the end, because the output string ends with a newline "\n".

Comment: this assumes you are in `pwd`, how do you specify the directory you wish to inspect?

Comment: You're right. For that, you can use the `:cd` option. Will update answer